# VHDL top module problems

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I have this top module

```
entity top is
Port 
     ( 
              CLock : in  STD_LOGIC;
           LED : out STD_LOGIC_vector(3 downto 0);
              taster : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
              teste_led: out std_logic;
              i_led: out std_logic_vector (2 downto 0)
      );
end top;
architecture Behavioral of top is

component game
port    (     
              LED1 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
              winLed: out std_logic;
              switch: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
              pointerLED: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)      
        );
end component;
begin
game1:  game    port map(LED1 => LED, CLK => Clock, winLed => teste_led, Switch => taster , pointerLed => i_led);
end Behavioral;
```

which i cannot see why isn't working. I've tested the game module by it self, and it work as it should be, but when i add it to this top module, nothing happens on my FPGA, eventhoug i am not getting any errors or warning?? what Am i doing wrong.

```
NET "switch"        LOC = "G18";

    NET "taster<3>" LOC = "K17";
    NET "taster<2>" LOC = "K18";
    NET "taster<1>" LOC = "H18";
    NET "taster<0>" LOC = "G18";

    NET "teste_led"     LOC = "R4";

    NET "i_led<2>"          LOC = "F4";
    NET "i_led<1>"          LOC = "P15";
    NET "i_led<0>"          LOC = "E17";

    NET "LED<3>"        LOC = "K14";
    NET "LED<2>"        LOC = "K15";
    NET "LED<1>"        LOC = "J15";
    NET "LED<0>"        LOC = "J14";


    NET "CLock"         LOC = "B8";
```

I did it exactly like this 
http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~strouce/class/elec4200/vhdhier.pdf
I am therefore very confused on what i've done wrong.. 
Complete code: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mro1wmk2bjkigp1/randomnumber.rar

Comment: Could you post your ucf file please?

Comment: top port ucf added

Comment: what is your clock frequency and is that your entire ucf?

Comment: that is my entire .ucf for my top module. 
50 Mhz

Comment: Is there some other way I can see all the build report files? That link requires their downloader app. Dropbox, perhaps?

Comment: Complete code added

Comment: It works now.. no idea why

Comment: Did you re-build the firmware?

Comment: I did a lot of random things which concluded with it ending working for that one component, when i Add another one  it mess it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your code looks fine. It's difficult to say what the problem is without seeing the build report files.

The Xilinx tools need to be told what the clock frequency of your clock is. This can be done by modifying your clock constraint as follows:

```
NET "CLock"         LOC = "B8" | PERIOD = 50 MHz;
```

It's possible that the first time you were just lucky that the router met timing spec, and the second time round it didn't.